# TypeScript: generic function type argument is inferred from a wrong parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below, if I don't specify `T` explicitly at function call, like `getOrPut<Item>(...)`, it's inferred from the `create` param, as a result the created item type may be incompatible with the `obj` dictionary, see the last line of the code for an example.

```js
function getOrPut<T>(
    obj: { [key: string]: T | undefined },
    key: string,
    create: () => T
): T {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (value) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return obj[key] = create();
    }
};

type Item = { title: string };
type Dictionary = { [key: string]: Item };
const dictionary: Dictionary = {};

// the foo type is {} but I expect Item
const foo = getOrPut(dictionary, 'foo', () => ({}));
```

Is it possible to force the `T` to be inferred from the `obj` param?

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICcAKIoA8AKgHwAUAUItYnAEYBWAXIgN6IDaA1qgJ4sBnKFhhhkAXRZFEAH0TgAJqmCjUCxAF8ANFRo9+iISLE6aiCFlQBDKKhZkAlIgC8JREQoOpbXdQgIhRAA3KwAbEFQXWkZuPnEAbl9EGGBEMhDw1CdWJLNLKBAsJAyIxLMNRFRQgUicszz0QqR6BljecSiLa1tHMpoNCg1EiiheAAdIgElbAFso9lgoULtDYVFkTUTRicQAERhoeDArLF55zn1BNbFJRGnUOYH-MECFA9gEE4N9w8-T+aGFAoAHpgYgoAALSLAOBwcHjSIwARsCp0fB3SoADwm0Duswoz0CMLhzhQ6GweCgZDev2Opy0iAA5MTGQzHC43GRWBoHA5EkA).

Comment: @griFlo Because `getOrPut` it's an utility function, I want to make it usage as simple as possible. In some cases the item type can be complex, for example `{ [key: string]: { title: string } }`, or `{ [key: string]: Omit<Item, 'foo'> }`. It's inconvenient to specify such complex type at every function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by specifying the `create` return type in terms of `obj` type:

```js
function getOrPut<T>(
    obj: { [key: string]: T | undefined },
    key: string,
    create: () => NonNullable<typeof obj[string]>
): T { ... }
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the solution works only since TypeScript `3.6.3` while my current version is `3.5.3`, but it should be updated soon. I'm not sure it's the best solution, may be there is a better one.

[Playgound link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=18&ssc=40&pln=18&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICcAKIoA8AKgHwAUAUItYnAEYBWAXIgN6IDaA1qgJ4sBnKFhhhkAXRZFEAH0TgAJqmCjUCxAF8ANFRo9+iISLE6aiCFlQBDKKhZkAlIgC8JRADkE7kABsfVuh9UAiheAAdUOGBaRg4jUQkSCgcpNl1qCAQhRAA3Kx8QVBcYhm4+cQBudMQYaLI8gtQnVmqzSygQLCQGwqqzDURUHwEilrM29E6kelL9cWKLa1tHPpoNCg0qilCIxABJWwBbYvZYKCDBYQTNKp2igBEYaHgwKyxeE859S+MJFgPUMd1pkwNkFE9YAg3gZHs8oe8TpsKBQAPQoxBQAAWRWAcDgGPCRRgAn2R0QVhJqAAHhFoGoAIQUEHZXH45wodDYPBQMjguGvd5aRAAclZwqFjhcbjIrA0DgcVSAA).

Answer (score 0):

It does work, you have to pass an `Item` in the `create` argument.

```js
function getOrPut<T>(
    obj: { [key: string]: T | undefined },
    key: string,
    create: () => T
): T {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (value) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return obj[key] = create();
    }
};

type Item = { title: string };
type Dictionary = { [key: string]: Item }
const dictionary: Dictionary = {};

// the foo type is {} but I expect Item{
const foo = getOrPut(dictionary, 'foo', () => ({} as Item)); // <--- casting here
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICcAKIoA8AKgHwAUAUItYnAEYBWAXIgN6IDaA1qgJ4sBnKFhhhkAXRZFEAH0TgAJqmCjUCxAF8ANFRo9+iISLE6aiCFlQBDKKhZkAlIgC8JREQoOpbXdQgIhRAA3KwAbEFQXWkZuPnEAbl9EGGBEMhDw1CdWJLNLKBAsJAyIxLMNRFRQgUicszz0QqR6BljecSiLa1tHMpoNCg1EiiheAAdIgElbAFso9lgoULtDYVFkTUTRicQAERhoeDArLF55zn1BNbFJRGnUOYH-MECFA9gEE4N9w8-T+aGFAoAHpgYgoAALSLAOBwcHjSIwARsCp0fB3SoADwm0Dusxyz0CMLhzhQ6GweCgZDev2Opy0iAA5MTGQzHC43GRWBUrMj7jMHA5EkA)

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer a solution without type casting. Actually I've just found a workaround, I will add my own an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: that was just an example of course, the solution will heavily depend on the type itself and how you want to handle it 